# /usr/bin/dpkg issue when installing apache

Tags: server, apt, package-management, apache2, dpkg

I think  I may have deleted an important directory while uninstalling apache
I'm experiencing the following issue when trying to install Apache:

```
Setting up apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.4) ...
cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/apache2/default-site/index.html': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
apache2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 187 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.4) ...
cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/apache2/default-site/index.html': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What command did you use? Give me a ping with @A.B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run those commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then now try to purge apache

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2  apache2-data apache2-utils
```

Comment: Makes subsequent re-installation of Apache2 even more problematic.